# htaccess Rules convert to NGINX is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I want to convert these simple rules in NGINX, i used this website (https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) to convert for me the rules, but somehow, instead of going to the page is downloading the page when i click on it.

Here is the example:

I want to convert these rules to NGINX:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^play/(.*)$ play.php?show=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?show=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/(.*)$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms/(.*)$ terms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms$ terms.php [L]
```

Here is what the website gave me:

```
# nginx configuration
location /play {
rewrite ^/play/(.*)$ /play.php?show=$1 break;
}
location /category {
rewrite ^/category/(.*)$ /category.php?show=$1 break;
}
location /contact {
rewrite ^/contact/(.*)$ /contact.php break;
}
location = /contact {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /contact.php break;
}
location /terms {
rewrite ^/terms/(.*)$ /terms.php break;
}
location = /terms {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /terms.php break;
}
```

Someone Can help me?
Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `break` here. You should be using `last`.

The purpose of `break` is to continue processing within the *current* location block. In each of the cases above, you require processing to move to the `location \.php$` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.